# Выполнить функцию js при нажатии определенного элемента

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу выполнить функцию `go2` при нажатии на `button` не выполняя функцию `go`

```js
function go($i) {
  alert($i);
}
function go2($i) {
  alert($i);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="go('159');">
<button onclick="go2('160');">Go 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийТихии при чем тут смысл? В описании все написано для чего и как.